# String toString() formatting using StringBuilder on game Bridge

Tags: java

I need some help formatting within this String method.

Right now my coding for printing is really messed up, and I had it so my code was almost printing in the right format except 13 cards were not being printed out.

My messy code as follows.

```
    /**
     * Will print out the hand information in a neat format using a 
     * StringBuilder will print 4 cards containing rank,suit,points each line
     * in order from Clubs,Diamonds,Hearts,Spades if no cards of the suit it 
     * will print a blank line
     */
    public String toString()
    {
        StringBuilder hand = new StringBuilder();
// 
//         for (int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
//             char suit = cards[i].getSuit();
//         }
            // 
            //             for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            //                 if (suit == 'C')
            //                     hand.append(cards[j] + "  ");
            //                 else if (suit == 'D')
            //                     hand.append(cards[j] + "  ");
            //                 else if (suit == 'H')
            //                     hand.append(cards[j] + "  ");
            //                 else if (suit == 'S')
            //                     hand.append(cards[j]);
            //                 else if (j == 4) 
            //                     hand.append("\n");
            //             }
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                if (cards[j].getSuit() == 'C')
                    hand.append(cards[j] + "  ");
                else if (j == 4) 
                    hand.append("\n");
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                if (cards[j].getSuit() == 'D')
                    hand.append(cards[j] + "  ");
                else if (j == 4)
                    hand.append("\n");
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                if (cards[j].getSuit() == 'H')
                    hand.append(cards[j] + "  ");
                else if (j == 4)
                    hand.append("\n");
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                if (cards[j].getSuit() == 'S')
                    hand.append(cards[j]);
                else if (j == 4)
                    hand.append("\n");
            }

            return hand.toString();
        }
```

An example of this current code:

```
Printing North Hand:  13 high card, 2 distribution points (15 total points)
 7C (0)   KC (3)   4D (0)  
 KH (3)  
 2S (0)


Printing South Hand:  19 high card, 2 distribution points (21 total points)
 5C (0)  
 AD (4)   3D (0)  
 7H (0)   6H (0)  


Printing East Hand:  7 high card, 2 distribution points (9 total points)


 2H (0)   3H (0)   4S (0) KS (3) 5S (0)


Printing West Hand:  1 high card, 1 distribution points (2 total points)
 6C (0)  10C (0)  
 JD (1)  
 8H (0)   6S (0)
```

Also I need to have it so my end code is printed out in this format(example).

```
Printing North Hand:  16 high card, 0 distribution points (16 total points)
 8C (0)  7C (0)  AC (4)  5C (0) 
10D (0)  KD (3)  QD (2) 
 2H (0)  5H (0)  3H (0) 
 7S (0)  AS (4)  KS (3)

Printing South Hand:  11 high card, 1 distribution points (12 total points)
 2C (0)  KC (3) 
 7D (0)  4D (0)  AD (4)  5D (0) 
10H (0)  KH (3)  JH (1)  7H (0) 
 6S (0)  5S (0)  3S (0)

Printing East Hand:  6 high card, 0 distribution points (6 total points) 
10C (0)  9C (0)  QC (2)  
 8D (0)  9D (0)  3D (0)  
 6H (0)  8H (0)  4H (0)  QH (2)  
 9S (0)  QS (2)  4S (0) 

Printing West Hand:  7 high card, 1 distribution points (8 total points)
 4C (0)  JC (1)  3C (0)  6C (0) 
 6D (0)  JD (1)  2D (0) 
 AH (4)  9H (0) 
 JS (1)  2S (0) 10S (0)  8S (0)
```

Comment: Not quite clear what is the desired result

Comment: The code on the very bottom is what I need as my result.

Comment: Don't use `\t`, use `String#format` which will allow to set the number of characters each column should have.  Take a look at [Formatted Strings](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_formatted_strings.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only 5 cards are coming out in total because you loop over the same range [0..4] for each suit. Well there is no way more than 5 can be printed, so I think it should be this:

```
for (Card card : cards) {
   if(card.getSuit() == 'C')
       hand.append(card + "  ");
}
hand.append("\n"); //I just moved this line out of loop
```

Then just do this for all suits:

```
for (Char suit : new Char[]{'C', 'D', 'H', 'S'}) {
  for (Card card : cards) {
     if(card.getSuit() == suit)
        hand.append(card + "  ");
  }
  hand.append("\n");
}
```